# How can I map one custom Entity to some database tables in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have a database first model in my project. The 3 tables `Document`, `DocumentItem` and `Product` are imported from the database.
[image]
I want to create a new Entity named `Order` that joins some fields of these three database tables. I created that Entity as you see in the first picture and filled its table mapping as you see in the second picture.
[image]
After the build of the project I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 193:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Product.Id) of table Product.    EFTest  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EFTest\EFTest\Data\EfTest.edmx    194 
Error       Error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 186:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Document.Id) of table Document.  EFTest  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EFTest\EFTest\Data\EfTest.edmx    187 
Error       Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 193:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Orders.Id) of the EntitySet Orders.  EFTest  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EFTest\EFTest\Data\EfTest.edmx    194 
Error       Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 186:Must specify mapping for all key properties (Orders.Id) of the EntitySet Orders.  EFTest  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EFTest\EFTest\Data\EfTest.edmx    187
```

I could not find the source of the problem. How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Did you check the database structure is mapping to your design scheme correctly ? for example : is product.Id is defined as primary key in your db ?

Comment: @HanyHabib Yes it is OK.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest thing be to create Order as a view in the DB then use that view as your new entity ?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells ***there's a foreign key missing in your project !***

**Considering that you know** You cannot simply add tables from the database into your model and then create a new association in the model. By default it uses independent association which must be mapped to its database counterpart(e.g the relation must exists in the database as well). You must model your relation as `FK` association but it allows only *one-to-one* and *one-to-many* associations. **In another words**, when you add a new table with "Include foreign key columns in the model" checked in EF4 and the table doesn't contain any foreign key relationships then you try to add a association it will trigger this error. The solution is to [Define Constraints in an EF4 model that don’t exist in the database.](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/defining-constraints-in-an-ef4-model-that-dont-exist-in-the-database/)

Sometimes we have unwanted conflicts which can cause such this problems when you can delete the table from the EF designer and also delete everything related to that table manually (in the XML file), then add the table again and put the right mappings again.